# Prefix Error in Production | Symfony 5 | No route found

Tags: symfony, routes, prefix

I got the following strange behaviour in production.  the twig command `{{ path('recherche') }}` thows a critical error log but does not stop the rendering process:
*Unable to generate a URL for the named route "recherche"*

It seems that it comes from the locale. 2 Prefixes are defined in annotations.yml :

```
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: 
        html: ''
        amp: '/amp'
```

when I add the _locale as param `{_locale: 'html' }`, there's no error

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are misusing the routing rules.

Prefixes (and paths) are single-valued parameters.
Multiple values are accepted only on in case of [Localized Routes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n) (that's why does not throw any error when passing a `_locale` parameter).

The only thing you can do without extending the builtin router is to specify two different route prefixes like:

```yaml
web:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

amp:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    name_prefix: 'amp_'
    prefix: '/amp'
```

And then call a custom twig function that evaluates the context (amp or not) and calls the router with the correct target route name (with or without the 'amp_' prefix)

Comment: Thanks man! I was struggling with api_platform and the task to add a second, internal route for all the api endpoints (multiple prefixes). So I added a second prefix in yaml-array style, which basically worked, but I got weird route names, who couldn't be identified when generating an openapi.yml file because of the route names. They ended in `.0` and `.1`. 
Now I created two route definitions like in your post and that worked out very well. That saved me 8+ hours of overwriting/decorating the PathResolver of the api_platform. Thank you so much, Alessandro!